# String to DateTime conversion fails

Tags: c#, datetime, type-conversion

I have to parse an import file which contains datetimes in the following format:

> "2016-12-02T09:23:20+01:00"
>   "2016-12-08T15:31:49+01:00"

I guess this corresponds to

> "yyyy-MM-ddThh:mm:sszzz"

My problem is that when I try to convert this string to a date it works for the first date but not for the second. The second fails on the hour 15. If I change that to 11 for example it works again.
So it seems this format is not using a 24 hours notation.

My code for converting is this :

```
string test = "2016-12-02T09:23:20+01:00";
DateTime dateTest = DateTime.ParseExact(test, "yyyy-MM-ddThh:mm:sszzz", System.Globalization.CultureInfo.CurrentCulture);
```

this works, but when I do

```
string test = "2016-12-08T15:31:49+01:00";
DateTime dateTest = DateTime.ParseExact(test, "yyyy-MM-ddThh:mm:sszzz", System.Globalization.CultureInfo.CurrentCulture);
```

This fails with  exception :

> String was not recognized as a valid DateTime.

My question is, how can I convert dates in this format to a datetime ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use upper case `HH` for 24h clock.

this should work:

```
string test = "2016-12-08T15:31:49+01:00";
DateTime dateTest = DateTime.ParseExact(test, "yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:sszzz", System.Globalization.CultureInfo.CurrentCulture);
```